# Updating column in database with new values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to update a column on an oracle database with new values which have been calculated and inputted into a pandas dataframe. The table name in the database is protein_info and the column I want to update is pct. I'm getting the following error when I run my code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./update_nsaf.py", line 81, in 
df.to_sql(protein_info, engine, index=False,  if_exists='replace')
AttributeError: type object 'protein_info' has no attribute 'lower'

```
df = df[['id', 'pct']]
engine=create_engine('oracle://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase', echo=False)
connect = engine.raw_connection()
df.to_sql(protein_info, engine, index=False,  if_exists='replace')
sql = """ 
    UPDATE protein_info
    SET protein_info.pct = pct
    FROM protein_info
    WHERE protein_info.id = id
"""
connect.execute(sql)
connect.close()
```

Comment: you're doing the update twice aren't you? once with pandas then once with your oracle connection driver also you didn't specify your schema in the df to sql. i'd recommend going over the docs in great detail before doing anything database related!

Comment: Yes I'm querying from the database and putting those values in a pandas dataframe then recalculating the values. Afterwards, I want to take those new values and put them back into the same column. I specified the schema as none, but I am still getting the same error.